# Adding a Field to AbstractUser results in an Operationalerror: no such column

Tags: python, sql, django

I added this field to AbstractUser:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    listed = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then I did

```
python makemigrations
python migrate
```

And it says that no changes were detected, dont'really know why. I've just added a field

Then I refreshed my localhost and I get  the following error:

```
no such column: auctions_user.listed
```

And the error points to this line of code `if request.user.is_authenticated:`

If i delete the field, everything goes back to normal, but i dont know why im getting this error

EDIT:
Initial migrations:

```
operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('listed', models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
```

Comment: Is tehere a comma (`,`) at the end of you `listed = ...` line?

Comment: Is the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` and do you have an initial migration for the app?

Comment: should my migrations be commerce/auctions/migrations/__pycache__ here? my app is in installed apps

Comment: If you have an initial migration it will be named `commerce/auctions/migrations/0001_initial.py`

Comment: Oh I had it, but I deleted it and did everything again. Now I dont have it, even if i makemigrations and migrate

Comment: If you don't have an initial migration you have to pass the app name when you call `makemigrations` to create the initial migration - `python manage.py makemigrations auctions`. Although if you already have tables created for your app but have deleted the migration you have other issues

Comment: Oh ok, now I have the initial migrations. If i look into that file, the field I want to add doesnt appears

Comment: Can you add the part of the migration that creates your model to the question?

Comment: Ok there it is.. Now it looks like the listed field exists, it appears now. But the error doesnt go away

Comment: You need to run `python manage.py migrate` to add the column to your database. Seems like you already ran an old migration but deleted it, is it possible to you reset your database and start again?

Comment: Ok I could reset my db. Is there a command to do it?

Comment: Depends on the database, which one are you using?

Comment: sqlite. I could just manually delete the file called db.sqlite3, right?¿

Comment: Yup that would work

Comment: Ok, I've done it. It seems to be working. Thank you very much